# QueryManager UserQuery syntax

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to use the QueryManager to get some results, but I don't know what the variable name for the query in the UserQuery property of the QueryManager should be.

This works:

```
userQuery = String.Format("scope:\"Scope Name\"");
```

However, this doesn't pass on the actual query.

This doesn't work ('default' is the keyword searched on):

```
userQuery = "default scope:\"Scope Name\"";
```

(No results)

This also doesn't work:

```
userQuery = "(default) AND (Scope:Scope Name)";
```

(query malformed)

Does anyone know how to pass the actual query word to the UserQuery property *with* an extra parameter (like scope in this case)?

Comment: try `userQuery = "\"default\" Scope:Scope Name";`

Comment: @GintasK Unfortunately that doesn't work. It says it doesn't recognize the scope. If I change it to `userQuery = "\"default\" Scope:\"Experis Content\"";` it does, but it doesn't fetch results for the 'default' query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this works:

```
userQuery = "\"default\" Scope:\"Scope Name\"";
```

Hope this helps anyone...